# Subdomain ignoring margins from linked stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, margin, stylesheet

I am having a problem which I haven't run into before. I am working on a site http://recruitingprocessanalytics.redbranchmedia.com and when a user clicks to log in, it redirects to a subdomain http://app.recruitingprocessanalytics.com/. The subdomain is using the stylesheet from the main site. The problem is, it's ignoring some of the CSS rules, but not all of the them.

For example, look at the h1 "Demo" on the subdomain in developer tools. It's supposed to have a margin-top of 10px and I see it in developer tools, but it just isn't adding the margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

margin-top and margin-bottom are only working on block elements, not on inline elements!

You changed the usual behavior of the heading elements to display: inline; in the common.css-file, which prevents the margin from being shown.

I guess the common.css file is not used on http://recruitingprocessanalytics.redbranchmedia.com.

Change the behaviour to display: block;, then the margins will be shown!

Comment: Thank you! That was it exactly. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Great! Can you please mark my answer as your solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the margin-top: 10px inline in the HTML.  Like so:

```
<h1 style="margin-top:10px">Title</h1>
```

The reason I suggest this is to see if the style gets applied.  If it does, your problem is a problem of specificity, or something is over riding your CSS.

Check to see if the style sheets are linked in a different order.  Or, if maybe you already have an inline style in your h1 tag?

If it were me trying to debug this, I would start with an inline style.

Hope this helps!